# I tried to print out 1! to 10! but hit a runtimeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, runtime-error

Here is my code:

```
def factR(n):
  if n == 1:
    return n
  return n * factR(n-1)

for i in range (11):
  print factR(i)
```

The factR(n) function works fine. I have tested it. But after I have added the last two lines it returned a RuntimeError. May I know the reason?

Comment: Need atab indent before `print factR(i)`?

Comment: your code does not look correct intended. can you fix it?

Comment: @lucumt fixed. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: @NikosVitaTopiko Fixed. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: Not fixed, still not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't accounting for the condition where `n` equals to `0`, and yet your range starts from 0 (to 10). Since `0!` equals to `1`, you should simply change:

```
if n == 1:
    return n
```

to:

```
if n <= 1:
    return 1
```

With the change your code would output:

```
1
1
2
6
24
120
720
5040
40320
362880
3628800
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work for `n = 0`, it goes to infinite recursion. `range(11)` goes for i from 0 to 10.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want `0!`, just replace `range(11)` by `range(1,11)`. Otherwise, just follow the above suggestions by other users.